# My References citations in text is too long

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm writing a paper for Springer journal and my .bib file is like below:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{RN34,
   author = {Hu, Xiaoqing and Bao, Ming and Zhang, Xiao-Ping and Guan, Luyang and Hu, Yu Hen},
   title = {Generalized Iterated Kalman Filter and its Performance Evaluation},
   journal = {IEEE Trans. Signal Processing},
   volume = {63},
   number = {12},
   pages = {3204-3217},
   year = {2015},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{RN34}

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{FinalSpringerRefs}

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem{Ref1}
Hu, X., Hu, Y.-H., Xu, B.: Generalised Kalman filter tracking with multiplicative measurement noise in a wireless sensor network. IET Signal Processing 8(5), 467-474 (2013).

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

when I want to use this reference in my text, its name is too long:

> [Hu et al.(2015)Hu, Bao, Zhang, Guan, and Hu]

I checked other papers from this journal and it should be something like this:

> (Maltoni et al. 2009)

How can I do that?
please guide me

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  could you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the preamble of the file `spbasic.sty`:

```
 % This is an author-year citation style bibliography. As such, it is
 % non-standard LaTeX, and requires a special package file to function properly.
 % Such a package is    natbib.sty   by Patrick W. Daly
```

In short, if you load the `natbib` citation management package, the output of citation call-outs will look fine.

Do encase the word "Kalman" in curly braces, though, to keep the name from getting lower-cased by the `spbasic` bibliography style.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{FinalSpringerRefs.bib}
@article{RN34,
   author = {Hu, Xiaoqing and Bao, Ming and Zhang, Xiao-Ping and Guan, Luyang and Hu, Yu Hen},
   title = {Generalized Iterated Kalman Filter and its Performance Evaluation},
   journal = {IEEE Trans. Signal Processing},
   volume = {63},
   number = {12},
   pages = {3204-3217},
   year = {2015},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}

\begin{document}
\cite{RN34}
\bibliography{FinalSpringerRefs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: *Addendum*: For parenthetic-style citation call-outs, such as "(Hu et al, 2015)", the `natbib` citation management package provides the command `\citep`.

Comment: I tried to add natbib but there was multiple errors. Then I reinstalled it, now I can't add .bib file to Winedt and I faced this error:
LaTeX Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 11. can you guide me ?

Comment: @EhsanFB - you wrote, "there was multiple errors" -- which errors, please? I'm afraid I am worthless at mind-reading. You should start by telling me which operating system (Windows?, MacOS?) you employ and which TeX distribution is installed on your system. Please also clarify what you mean by "now I can't add .bib file to Winedt".  WinEdt is just a front end -- there should be absolutely no need to "add [a] .bib file" to Winedt.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mico. Sorry, I'm a beginner in Latex and my question wasn't complete. My problem is solved with your help.